# How to change PI name and footnote in NIH documentclass?

Tags: document-classes

I am writing a proposal for a class and I am using `\documentclass{nih}` (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nih/). However, for the name of the PI, it shows "Donald, Bruce R." by default. How can I change this name to my own? Also, how can I change the text in the footnote? It says "PHS 398/2590 (Rev. 09/04)" on the left and "Continuation Format Page" on the right. I only want the page number and leave out the other stuff. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{nih}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Specific Aims}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Principal Investigator name can be set with `\piname`; the two parts of the footer can be nullified by standard `fancyhdr` commands:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{nih}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\lfoot{}
\rfoot{}

\piname{Donald Duck}

\begin{document}

\section{Specific Aims}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```